# PL/Python ERROR: NameError: global name 'name of user-defined function' is not defined

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested, nameerror, plpython

I am running Postgres 9.3 and I am trying to create a PL/Python function calling a user-defined sql function but I get the below error message after calling the function using `SELECT * FROM f2(TEXT1, TEXT2)`:

```
ERROR: NameError: global name 'f1' is not defined
SQL state: XX000
Context: Traceback (most recent call last):
PL/Python function "f2", line 1, in <module>
print f1() 
PL/Python function "f2"
```

The sql function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f1(TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS SETOF some_tbl AS $$
 SELECT col1, col2, col3
 FROM some_other_tbl
 WHERE col1=$1 AND col2=$2
 GROUP BY col1;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

And the PL/Python function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f2(TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS SETOF some_tbl
  AS $$ return f1() $$ 
  LANGUAGE 'plpython2u';
```

So, it seems the f1 is not found within f2, even though I can call it on its own.

Any pointers on this would be appreciated? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way.  An SQL function is not directly callable as a Python function.  (It might be a neat feature, but nothing of the sort is implemented.)  If you want to call SQL functions from PL/Python, you need to do

```
plpy.execute("SELECT f1(...)")
```

etc.